# Wordpress get_the_content_feed with paginated posts

Tags: php, wordpress, rss, feed

I have a wordpress site and i have been working on it's feed.
I noticed that when a post has been paginated with , it only renders the first page of the post.
What i need to do is get all the content of the post and not just the first page.

```
while( have_posts()) : the_post();

    ?>

<item>

    <title><?php the_title_rss(); ?></title>

    <link><?php the_permalink_rss() ?></link>

    <comments><?php comments_link_feed(); ?></comments>

    <pubDate><?php echo mysql2date('D, d M Y H:i:s +0000', get_post_time('Y-m-d H:i:s', true), false); ?></pubDate>

    <dc:creator><![CDATA[<?php the_author(); ?>]]></dc:creator>

    <?php
    $pub_date= mysql2date('D, d M Y H:i:s +0000', get_post_time('Y-m-d H:i:s', true), false);
......

    $description = get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_content; // The Description
    $content = get_the_content_feed('rss2');
```

Any advice?